# Is Black Ops 2 region locked?

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

So, my sister fell in love with Black Ops 2 during the free weekend and we decided to get it for her. However, the price is... shall we say, high. However, we found it relatively cheap on Amazon.com, but only if you buy the disc.

As such, I wanted to ask if Black Ops 2 is region locked? So if I order the disc from US and it arrives at Finland, will she still be able to play it? She does have Steam account, so that is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USA to Finland should be fine. I ordered the game from USA and have redeemed the key in India for Modern Warfare 3 and it works without a hitch.

The issue mainly arises if you buy the game from Russia and CIS. The game there will be even cheaper but it does have a region lock. So go ahead and get it. However I believe that the shipping that you will pay is quite high, find someone in the US and ship it to them and ask them to message you the key.